# Repeat function does not work with list Python

Tags: python, list, function, repeat

I have written a dice roller that generates random numbers and inserts them into a list. It then prints each iteration in the list.

This works the first time it runs. However, when asked "do you want to reroll?" and choosing 'y' I get a `StopIteration` error

Shouldn't Python just overwrite the list?

EDIT: Added more code

```
File "./test.py", line 159, in diceRoller
  sname = it1.next()
StopIteration




#imports

import random


#Stats start at 0

acc = 0
com = 0
con = 0
dex = 0
fig = 0
inl = 0
per = 0
str = 0
wil = 0


sname = 0
statList = ['Acc', 'Com', 'Con', 'Dex', 'Fig', 'Int', 'Per', 'Str', 'Wil']
it1 = iter(statList)



stat = []

def diceRoller():


  rollcount = 1
  index = 0
  print ' '
  print "Rolling 3 d6's for each stat"

  print fmtt.format(' ', 'Stat','Your rolls', 'Total', 'Stat value') 

  while rollcount < 10:

    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    die3 = random.randint(1,6)
    total = sum([die1,die2,die3])   

    rollcount += 1  


 (removed large if block - that sets bonus value)
  bonus = 4


for item in range(1):
  stat.append(bonus)

#print stat


#for i in range(1):
  sname = it1.next()


print fmt.format(' ', sname, die1, die2, die3, total, bonus)



  else:
    rroll = raw_input("Do you want to reroll? (y/n)")
    if rroll == 'y':
      diceRoller()
    else:
      statCalc()     

#### END DEF diceRoller
```

Comment: So what is `it1` in this code?

Comment: Also do you mean something like "calling a function again"? Because there is no `repeat()` here. (I thought from your title you might be using [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) or [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html))

Comment: That is the exception that is supposed to be thrown when an iterator runs out of values.. No where near enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: sorry, it1 refers to the iteration of my list 

it1 = iter(statList)

But basically what I want is for the function to re-run based on the answer. so if i choose 'y' , it runs the function agian and generates a new set of numbers

Comment: What's the deal with `for i in range(1)`? That will just loop once. Why not just have that code with no loop at all?

Comment: Ok, so I have to clarify again, I just realized what I didn't say

So i have 2 lists, one list is just a bunch of strings (statList), these don't change, the other list is stat, which holds variables that get generated and appended to the list

Comment: You need to show a more complete hunk of your code for us to understand what is going on.

Comment: Bigger hunk of code added

Comment: You only set `it1` once before the function, so once it runs out of values, it can't iterate any more, because it's out of values.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, with your answer and the one below from jcfollower, it clicked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send statList to the diceRoller function as a parameter and then put

```
it1 = iter(statList)
```

inside that function

Comment: Thanks! that did it much easier than I was expecting.